# Doxygen.h no such file or directory

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, nextion

I am interfacing arduino nano with nextion HMI. I am getting error doxygen.h not found, but this library is included in lib folder.

Comment: Please add information about your progress with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the folder hierarchy. It should look like this:

```
Arduino/libraries/Library_name/src/file.h
```

or

```
Arduino/libraries/Library_name/file.h
```

In this case it should look similar this:

```
Arduino/libraries/Doxygen/doxygen.h
```

Answer (score 0):

do a find / -name "doxygen.h" then do an strace to find where its being called and give the full path.